# Joining doesn't work when columns include apostrophes

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I'm trying to update id's in a table where the corresponding unique id is currently stored in another table.

Currently, the table structure is something like this:

**Table 1**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | As |
| 2 | Bs |
| 3 | C's |

**Table 2**

| id | name | pay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | As | 100 |
| null | Bs | 200 |
| null | C's | 300 |

```
UPDATE table2 t2
JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.name = t1.name
SET t2.id = t1.id
```

When I update the id's in table 2 by joining the names using the query above *As* and *Bs* get the correct id's, but all fields like *C's* don't find a match and result in having null id fields like below.

**Result**

| id | name | pay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | As | 100 |
| 2 | Bs | 200 |
| null | C's | 300 |

**Desired Result**

| id | name | pay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | As | 100 |
| 2 | Bs | 200 |
| 3 | C's | 300 |

Any way to get mySQL to correctly join names with apostrophes in them?

Comment: Probably the 2 values may seem the same but they are actually different. Check for spaces, unprintable characters or if the apostrophes are the same apostrophes.

Comment: joining absolutely will work, unless there is a problem with your code not handling apostrophes correctly or unless the apostrophes are not all actually the same character  (`'` vs `’` vs `‘`)

Comment: You absolutely have a data inconsistency as you can see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86fc5e922b0badde66acc91742e130bc) there's no issues with joining.

Comment: You guys were right, didn't realize there were different characters like apostrophes that @ysth mentioned. Doing a quick update with (set name = replace(name, ' ‘‘ ', ' '' ') fixed most of the problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apostrophe types were inconsistent.

In the comments @ysth mentioned there were different characters that are sometimes used as apostrophes, so replacing them all with the standard (') fixed most of the issues.